# Load overlay through URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following worked fine on a previous project, however on the current one it's not. Is there another way of loading a overlay through URL?

EXAMPLE:

www.url.com/terms and overlay comes down.

```
    url = window.location.href;

        if (url.indexOf('terms') == url.length -5)
            {
                overlay.fadeIn(400, function(){
                    box.fadeIn(t500);
                });
            }
```

Comment: I am trying to fix this one, but I can;t figure out so far what's wrong..

Comment: do `console.log(url)` (or `alert(url)` if you're reading this in 1996) after you assign the value and check what you're getting, just to be sure

Comment: Did that and it's getting the right URL however when I insert /terms it return a 404 page saying page not found, there must be something wrong somewhere as I used it before and it worked fine..

Comment: You need to fix that issue then, however it's arisen, before you can go any further.

Comment: How does your website know what file relates to /terms? What framework or CMS are you using?

Comment: @alro it's hand coded and since the terms and conditions are inside an overlay it needs to be accessed directly through URL too..

Comment: Since you're getting a 404 the Server / Browser clearly doesn't understand how he should handle the url `www.url.com/terms`. Standard behaviour would be to open the file "terms", which clearly doesn't exist.

Comment: Strangely works on my local machine (I am using mamp), but not on the staging version...